# Firebase phone authentication not sending message after upload app on playstore

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My app doesn't receive message after uploading it to the App Store.I have already copied the sh1 from play console and pasted to firebase console. But I'm unable to solve the problem.

I have tried many times fixing the problem and referring other similar problem faced by people but unable to find a solution. Would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

After Paste New Google SHA1 to firebase, you need to update google-services.json in your app too. then give update on your playstore, and you will able to receive notification.